# Accidentally deleted a system framework, macOS screwed!

Tags: macos, mac, finder, high-sierra

I accidentally deleted AddressBook.framework. Now when I restart my iMac the system can't load this framework thus nothing is working.

I have a bootable disk of macOS Sierra but going to recovery mode and installing macOS Sierra is not possible because downgrading High Sierra isn't allowed.

Formatting my disk will result in losing all my files because I don't have a Time Machine backup.

How can I restore AddressBook.framework to get my system working again.

[image]

Comment: Boot to Recovery Mode (cmd-R while booting) and reinstall High Sierra!

Comment: The question is clear. Are we now penalizing them like some game show host "please word it in the form of a question"?

Comment: @klanomath  I can't since my daily FUP limit is finished which is 1 GB

Comment: Recovery Mode should work without Internet access

Comment: If you don't have Time Machine backup but want one for next time, I can strongly recommend setting up a wireless one, like a Time Capsule.

Comment: Please stop bumping the q&a!

Comment: With other words: you fell in love with your question...

Comment: [Do not bump your questions.](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2731/37797)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually you would have to reinstall High Sierra in Recovery Mode. If you don't have access to another Mac running High Sierra locally and with limited download quota do the following:

- Ask someone to upload High Sierra's AddressBook.framework as zip somewhere (e.g. a file sharing host) and submit the download link.
- Boot to High Sierra's Recovery Mode.
- Open Terminal and disable SIP (which should be disabled anyway or you wouldn't have been able to delete the framework).
- Quit Terminal and open Safari. Enter the download link and save the zip file to /Volumes/< main_volume_name>/System/Library/Frameworks/

  Alternatively (if the link doesn't allow to choose a download location, which can occur on some file sharing hosts) open the Preferences in Safari and set in General > File download location > "Ask for each download":

  [image]

  Then save the file to /Volumes/< main_volume_name>/System/Library/Frameworks/:

  In the example below the name of the main volume is *System*. Your main volume name may be different (e.g. Macintosh HD or macOS).

  [image]

  [image]
- Open Terminal and enter:

  ```
  cd /Volumes/<main_volume_name>/System/Library/Frameworks/
  ```

  **Depending on your Safari settings the zip will be unzipped automatically after the download and the next two steps (unzip/rm) aren't necessary!**

  ```
  /Volumes/<main_volume_name>/usr/bin/unzip -a AddressBook.framework.zip
  rm AddressBook.framework.zip
  ```
- check codesigning:

  ```
  codesign -dv --verbose=4 AddressBook.framework
  ```

  if this step fails delete AddressBook.framework and get a proper one.
- Check the restricted flag:

  ```
  ls -laO AddressBook.framework
  ```

  which should show for . (the dot: . is the "bundle/package" AddressBook.framework here - the date will be different of course):

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x    7 root  wheel restricted 224 Sep 25 21.59 .
  ...
  ```

  (You may have to add the restricted attribute to AddressBook.framework later if it's missing)
- (Enable SIP) and reboot.

Comment: Can you upload the framework as zip?

Comment: And how to save the file to /Volumes/<​main_volume_name>/System/Library/Frameworks/ and what should I insert here: <​main_volume_name>

Comment: macOS sierra by default sets the name to macOS now you seem to be pretty active so can you upload the zip here https://dbr.ee

Comment: So now that the file is in its original location should I skip step 5?

Comment: Codesign step output: no such file or directory!

Comment: You said to continue with step 6 so I skipped all the previous steps!

Comment: Output for all the above mentioned steps: https://dbr.ee/bLzA

Comment: Hurrah! Everyhting working as smooth as butter and the file which you provide me was it off macOS Sierra or High Sierra and how can I introduce an exception for macOS to skip searching or loading this framework while booting up and loading all the files?

Comment: @Sayan It's the High Sierra version of course. I'd assume that all frameworks in /System/Library/Frameworks/ are required to boot and run macOS properly = those (and other files/bundles) **are** the normal operating system. You can't "skip" any of them.

Comment: @Sayan Now that things are working again, **make a backup of anything you don't want to lose!** Especially, do it before you do any more experimenting with the OS.

Comment: @GordonDavisson No questions asked, I did it as soon as I got my Mac working again!

Answer (score 4):

Ok I will give another easy answer first boot to recovery partition by holding CMD+R at startup chime then after it finishes booting click utilities in the upper panel then click terminal type csrutil disable then restart the your Mac 
Now once you hear the startup chime hold CMD+S till you see plain text now do the following steps:

• First type mount -uw /
• Then plug in another high capacity pendrive
• then type mkdir /usb 
• then type mount -t [filesyatem of pendrive] /dev/disk2s1 /usb

• Now we are going to copy the entire home directory from your MacBook to the pendrive
Tip: you can find out the size of your home directory by ls -la  /Users 
• Then type rsync -p -P -o /Users --exclude /Users/your username/Library /Users /usb

Then you can reinstall the OS again by asking a friend by giving a bootable os.

Comment: I was also thinking of a step like this but in a different way, I was trying to restore the Home directory via Disk Utility to an External USB Stick, but restoring was not successful, Disk utility was giving me an error like this that the drive is not Apple Format.....I don't remember the term!

Comment: Did you try my way it should not show any error this command is tested by me.

Comment: Actually the accepted answer is working, I got errors cause I skipped some steps, by the way your step is easy too!