# Accidentally moved framework file to trash and now finder continuously fails

Tags: mac, finder, crash, trash

I have the exact same problem as this person: [Accidentally deleted a system framework, macOS screwed!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300222/accidentally-deleted-a-system-framework-macos-screwed), except that I removed; `Social.framework`, `Weathkit.framework` and `ContactsAgent.framework`.

Finder reptitively fails saying it can't load the libraries. I can view the files in my `.Trash` directory via Terminal, however I've unsuccessfully attempted to move them back multiple times by executing `mv .Trash/Social.framework`.

Honestly, I really dont care about any of those apps but I want Finder to work.

If someone would please upload a zip file of those frameworks, so that I could do the same thing as Sayan and replace, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Best to boot into recovery disk and reinstall macos. This will not over right any if your data.also how did you move those files they are protected by sip.

Comment: @Mark possible case for a user level account cf an admin account perhaps.

Comment: @SolarMike I do not understand your comment

Comment: @Mark there are different account levels a user can be set to - ordinary user accounts can’t easily delete system files without entering the admin password...

Comment: @SolarMike But no user including admins can delete system files they are protected by SIP unless you have turned SIP off - which if you have you should already know enough to be able to restore the files.

Comment: @Mark if your last comment is true, then the OP cannot have a problem....

Comment: Failed to move them back multiple times?  Failed how?  Don't expect people to guess what you think you mean.  Provide details.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a duplicate of the linked questions - be sure to edit your post to explain how you can’t follow the several steps in the answers below to bring back the files. This is covered in several of the canonical questions on this site:

- [Where is the list of canonical questions stored for Ask Different?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different)

We strongly discourage any breaking of EULA / sharing of files and a strict reading of Apple’s license is you can’t redisctibute or derive new works from the OS they distribute. Since we’re not lawyers, we don’t try to pick apart where in the world or why an EULA may not apply due to local courts and local laws and just avoid this sort of thing entirely since we can’t really answer legal questions well here.

- [Accidentally deleted a system framework, macOS screwed!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300222/)
- [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/)